# Create patterns from URLs and discard the patterns having the most items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, list, url

I am developping a Chrome extension which, among other things, gets a (long) list of URLs in an array (or even at the console). I need to 'extract' the URLs matching the (arbitrary) patterns with the less entries in that list, completely discarding the patterns that have the most entries (say, more than 5 items).

I can't use a *classic / standard* regex for that, since, as I said, the patterns can be entirely different from one extension execution to another (aka they're arbitrary), but I still need to create those patterns (or ar least sort / group the list according to those patterns) in order to be able to eliminate the patterns having the most items in my list.

How do I do that in Javascript? My instinct is to either:

- Make some regex patterns from the entries (but their number is also
  arbitrary, so at first sight one can't know how many patterns to
  create), count the items belonging to each pattern and keep only the
  items that belong to patterns with no more than 5 items
- Compare the items' strings between each other, the way a similar
  names duplicate eliminator (e.g. [dupeGuru](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/)) would and keep only
  the 'similar duplicates' that have at most 5 items (but that would
  probably be beyond the scope of the extension and most likely doable
  in an easier / faster way)
- Sort the items in the list so that the patterns with the most items
  are the last, then take the first, say, 10 items in the list (aka
  those who belong to the patterns with the least entries) and process
  them further. This would be my preferred solution and probably one of
  the fastest, but the problem is that a simple alphabetical sort
  wouldn't work in every case, as the patterns with the most entries
  could be alphabetically anything (plus, they could be more patterns
  having lots of items).

Test case:

```
var list =
[
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-00.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-01.htm",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/items/othertext.com/textdesc.doc",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/334033.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/317651.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/336157.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/337299.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/317353.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/392056.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/144090.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/298691.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/236181.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/337211.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/337076.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/234047.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/399081.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/377117.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/311941.txt",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-02.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-03.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-04.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-05.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-06.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-07.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-08.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-09.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-10.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-11.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-12.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-13.htm",
"https://www.othertext.com/textid/textid-14.htm",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/sitetext/00372/00.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/items/othertext.com/randomtext/sitetext/0.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/315768.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/316775.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/338585.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/323557.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/338914.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/207143.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/347235.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/323878.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/184470.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/317344.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/331374.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/232198.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/275001.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/396962.txt",
"https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/339011.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/303454.txt",
"https://sometext3.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/336118.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext2/215/339482.txt"
];
```

In this case, I would like to keep only:

```
var result =
[
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/items/othertext.com/textdesc.doc",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/sitetext/00372/00.txt",
"https://sometext9.othertext.com/items/othertext.com/randomtext/sitetext/0.txt"
];
```

since these items belong to the patterns with 5 items at most.

A simple code sample or an explained method would be great.

Comment: What is the logic used to select URLs?

Comment: @guest271314: The logic behind grouping them into patterns is more or less a combination of URL address and URL path similarity (for example, `https://sometext2.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/377117.txt` and `https://sometext9.othertext.com/textagain/moretext/158/311941.txt` have the same path logic, being different on just a few characters within the URL address or path, enough to make them 'similar' for the human eye). The logic used to select the _result_ URLs is is simply adding all the items of the patterns that have no more than 5 items under their 'belt' to the `result` array.

Comment: Why are not three more URLs beginning with `"https://www.othertext.com/textid/"` not pushed to `result`?

Comment: Good catch - my mistake, I'll edit the question accordingly; I made the error because the first part of the pattern items were separated by the other part by the items beginning with `https://sometext[number].othertext.com`. The URLs beginning with `https://www.othertext.com/textid/` should actually be _completely discarded_ from the result, since their number is way more than 5. By the way, patterns with more than 5 items should be completely discarded, instead of adding 5 of their items to the result, like your last reply implied.